# Shell script: getopt: what does --) mean?

Tags: bash, shell, getopt

I'm writing a shell script to process the argument list, and I used `getopt`.
But I found that it is not working as expected.
I managed to narrow the bug down to these lines:

```
case "$1" in
.....
--)
shift
break
;;
```

I can see that `--)` always match for the `case` no matter what argument I provide(e.g. `./run -r -d` or `./run`). I'm not sure what this "`--`" means or is supposed to do

I googled a lot but none of the results explain what this "`--`" means.

My shell script is as below and I can see that `echo "in --)"` always prints. I'm not sure what is the meaning of this `in --)`

```
OPTIONS=di:r:v
LONGOPTIONS=debug,inputdir:,random:,verbose

PARSED=$(getopt --options=$OPTIONS --longoptions=$LONGOPTIONS --name "$0" -- "$@")
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "I’m sorry, `getopt` failed in this environment."
    exit 2
fi

eval set -- "$PARSED"

echo "$#"


while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -d|--debug)
            d=y
            shift
            ;;
        -i|--inputdir)
            inputFolder=y
            folder="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -v|--verbose)
            v=y
            shift
            ;;
        -r|--random)
            randNumFile="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        --)
            echo "in --)"   #this echo always prints
            shift
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "arguments error"
            exit
            ;;
    esac
done

echo "$#"
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's `man getopt`:

> Normally, no non-option parameters output is generated until all options and their arguments have been generated.  Then '--' is generated as a single parameter, and after it the  non-option  parameters  in  the  order they were found, each as a separate parameter.

In other words, `getopt` generates a `--` after all options so you know when to stop looping over them. All words after `--` should be treated as non-option arguments, even if they start with a dash.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you!